# Building Qt6 Qt Creator inside Docker Ubuntu

Tags: docker, qt-creator, qt6, ubuntu-22.04

My goal is to install and run Qt Creator inside of Docker container. I downloaded Ubuntu image from hub and ran `apt-get update && apt-get install ubuntu-server -y`. (I'll be using VcXsrv X Server to launch GUI).
I was trying to download and build Qt Creator using info from this link [https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Creator_from_Git_on_Ubuntu_22.04](https://stackoverflow.com) as a guide, every other step was successfull except the build part.

Sadly, downloading binaries from the site is not an option for now.

Running the first line from step 6 of that guide has returned an error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6QmlCompilerPrivate/Qt6QmlCompilerPrivateTargets.cmake:108 (message):
  The imported target "Qt6::QmlCompilerPrivate_resources_1" references the
  file

     "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/objects-None/QmlCompilerPrivate_resources_1/.rcc/qrc_builtins.cpp.o"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6QmlCompilerPrivate/Qt6QmlCompilerPrivateTargets.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6QmlCompilerPrivate/Qt6QmlCompilerPrivateConfig.cmake:60 (include)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake:219 (find_package)
  src/plugins/qmldesigner/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

qtchooser returned:

```
qtchooser -print-env
QT_SELECT="qt6"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/qt6/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

All files seems to be in place, so I'm not really know where to look for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you got anywhere with this, but I had a similar problem and solved it by checking out an older version from the repo. e.g. v10.0.1

Comment: Thanks for the info, it helped me too, not sure why develop branch has this bug, but at least 10.0 branch is working

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs in `qmldesigner`.

If you don't need the QML Designer plugin, you can configure Qt Creator with `-DWITH_QMLDESIGNER=OFF` and this error should go away.